# Crash in AVAudioSession currentRoute

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, avaudiosession

We have received a number of crash reports from the app. They all look similar. The call [AVAudioSession currentRoute] is on the top of each crashed stack:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)  
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c0b25beb8  
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11  
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb  
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]  
Triggered by Thread:  14  
...  

Thread 14 name:  
Thread 14 Crashed:  
0  libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 16  
1  AVFAudio          -[AVAudioSession currentRoute] + 140 (AVAudioSession.mm:1715)  
...
```

We found that the crash happens in the handler of AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification notification. In this handler we are posting an asyncronous call on our custom serial queue, where we are getting the current route and enumerating through all the outputs.

```
- (instancetype)init  
{  
    if (self = [super init])  
    {  
          _commandsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.app.commandsQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);  
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
              selector:@selector(handleRouteChanged:)  
              name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification  
              object:nil];  
    }  
    return self;  
}  

- (void)handleRouteChanged:(NSNotification *)notification  
{  
    dispatch_async(self.commandsQueue, ^{  
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];  
        AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* currentRoute = audioSession.currentRoute;  
        for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *outputPort in currentRoute.outputs)  
        {  
            if ([outputPort.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortAirPlay])  
            {  
                // updating dictionary with status  
            }  
        }  
    });  
}
```

We are not able to reproduce the issue and we do not know the exact scenario. We played a lot with different route change scenarios, but we observed no crashes.
Does anyone have an idea about any possible root cause of this crash?

Comment: Hello, @Mxdq, any updates on this issue?

Comment: Got the same crash but don't know the reason. Maybe it's a race condition: currentRoute was called while the AirPlay was disabling or enabling. Could also be related to mixed scenarios: AirPlay with Headphones / other outputs.

Comment: We did not find the root cause. Asked on Apple dev forums and created tech request - no success. Are you able to reproduce it? We are not able and this is the problem. We see this crash in crash reports from users only.

Comment: @Mxdq did crash happens on all iOS versions ? or maybe on jailbroken devices ?

Comment: I have the same problem. 23 people: all iOS 11. No jailbreak.

Comment: Today I found one interesting thing. Not sure if it is related to the initial topic or not. If I just call _audioSession.currentRoute_ I'm getting a memory leak in _AVAudioSessionPortDescription_

Comment: @Mxdq It's happening only on Simulator. It's not happening on the real device.